# How to resolve reference issues in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to use Unity to move a gameobject with a script. When I add a new script the generic script that visual studio creates can't seem to find some of the references. For instance,

```
using UnityEngine;

public class moveObject : MonoBehaviour
```

intellisense doesn't seem to think UnityEngine and Monobehaviour exist to call things from. 
Again, I'm very new so if I haven't explained this correctly I'm sorry, any help is greatly appreciated.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Visual Studio and Unity and searched the forums here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationalSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate();
    }
}
```

I expect the script to use the UnityEngine reference and call the transform method.

Comment: Hi @Nicholas, welcome to SO. Did you make sure the libraries you are using are compatible with the version of .NET your projects are configured for? A discrepancy will cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: JuanR Thanks for the response. I'm sure a sound like a bumbling fool but how do I make sure the libraries are compatible with .NET? I'm using a fairly new laptop with windows 10 and I just downloaded visual studio and .NET components today.

Comment: Right click on the project and select `Properties`. On the left, click on `Application`. See what target framework is configured for your projects.

Comment: By the way, you need to do this for each project.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.